# Eliminar registro en tablas relacionales

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito eliminar un registros de una tabla relacional, el dato esta en la tabla principal, como muestro en la imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para ello tengo la siguiente consulta que se ejecuta sin error pero no me afecta los registros:

```
DELETE FROM usuario
WHERE EXISTS (DELETE usuario, usuario_permiso 
FROM usuario, usuario_permiso 
WHERE usuario.idusuario = '25'
AND usuario_permiso.idusuario = '25')
```

Comment: Revisa en la configuración de tabla usuario_permiso, especificamente en "constraints" donde está la clave foranea. Si dice "MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION" significa que no va a borrar automáticamente esa referencia y debes cambiarlo a ON DELETE CASCADE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes configurar tu clave foranea como `"ON DELETE CASCADE"`. Probablemente esté por defecto en `"MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION"`

Para ello debes dirigirte a la tabla especifica (**usuario_permiso** en tu caso) y revisar en la declaración de claves la clave foranea `idusuario`. Allí observarás lo que te comenté en el parrafo anterior. Debes actualizar tu clave foranea a `"ON DELETE CASCADE"` que significa si borras un registro en la tabla "padre" también eliminalo en la tabla hijo asociada, es decir, si borras un registro en la tabla **"usuario"** borra también en **"usuario_permiso"** todo aquello asociado al `idusuario` seleccionado.

Un ejemplo en PostgreSQL sería:

[image: clave foranea]

Al crear la clave foránea colocar en su configuración **"On Delete"** la opción **"CASCADE"** como lo muestra la imagen anterior de esa forma garantizas que se solucione tu problema

**Observación:** Por regla general este tipo de "configuración" o "restricción" se realiza al momento de diseñar el esquema de la base de datos para evitar complicaciones una vez esté en entorno de producción la base de datos